# How do I determine if my external website user is actually inside our office network?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I've looked at the existing questions/responses in StackOverFlow and there were no working answers so I'm posting this question. Our website is an C# MVC site that uses Javascript for validation etc.

The scenario is this:

We want to display a message in our external website to users (employees) who are actually accessing it from within our office network.  The message would remain hidden for users who are outside our network (general public).

Please note that an internal office user is going out to the internet and hitting our external website so they would have a public IP address (not their local network IP) and I can't rely on that public IP address remaining consistent so I can't use the IP as the determining factor.

I would think that this would require a client-side solution but I've looked into JS possible solutions and none have worked.

Can anyone think of a way to determine if the user visiting out external website is an employee or part of the general public?

Comment: Maybe you can use different domains names for internal and external network.

Comment: If you cannot depend on user IP than you can't... Especially if it's important... Because there are solutions like service installed on client which would response on localhost or checking for well know server which can be only access inside

Comment: You could change your office dns server to resolve a completely different web site. Or route all office traffic through a web proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I ended up going a slightly different route which I has seen suggested in another post on another website I believe...I just didn't know if it would work but it does seem to work.

I put a reference to a .JS file that sits on one of our internal network servers . That JS changes the display value for the message I want do display which is initially hidden. So for the general public the message remains hidden, but for anyone on our network it will unhide the message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, however putting anything inside a JS file would still be visible if someone was to inspect it in their browser since it's essentially downloaded when the client browses the site. Just ensure nothing sensitive is added to the message such as a link to an employee only portal, as you'll expose the URL for potential attacks.

Comment: You're right Owen, and I did consider that but the only thing the JS does is unhide the element with the message so I think the risk is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a 'beacon' on a machine in your local network. It would connect to your web server every 5 seconds, and inform your web server of the dynamic IP address that your office network is currently being assigned by your ISP to access the external internet.

Now, your web server knows which IP address to display the special message to.

Note that you will need to check that your office internet service provider is not using [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). This will cause an issue, because a member of the public might be assigned an originating IP address that is the same as one used by people on your office network.

Another approach would be to set up a proxy server inside your local network, which would inject a special header into outgoing requests to your public web server if it sees that the request originates internally. You would configure your office router to force all web traffic through this proxy. The proxy would need to have a valid HTTPS certificate for the web server's domain name, so that is able to alter HTTPS traffic.